# Type parameter declaration in Scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I am newbie and learning Scala programming. I am struggling with following code. if I tried to replace "(Double, Double)" in "def combine" function with declared type "typeDouble" then why it is not working. 
code is :

```
type typeDouble = (Double,Double)
def foo: (Double,Double) => Double = (x: Double,y:Double) => x*y
def combine(x: Double, y: Double, z: Double, fun1 : typeDouble => Double) = fun1(fun1(x,y), z)
combine(1,2,3, foo)
```

compiler says :

```
type mismatch;
 found   : (Double, Double) => Double
 required: A$A228.this.typeDouble => Double
    (which expands to)  ((Double, Double)) => Double
combine(1,2,3, foo);}
           ^
```

Please explain the concept what is going wrong ?

Comment: Note: This is bit too verbose: `def foo: (Double,Double) => Double = (x: Double,y:Double) => x*y`, you could avoid repeating the type names: `def foo: (Double,Double) => Double = (x,y) => x*y`, or `def foo = (x: Double,y : Double) => x*y`.

Answer (score 3):

While parameter lists and tuples are both written in parentheses, they are not the same thing. By defining `type typeDouble = (Double,Double)` you define a tuple of two doubles. Then `fun1 : typeDouble => Double` is a function accepting not two parameters, but a single parameter which needs to be a tuple.

In your error message note:

```
((Double, Double)) => Double
```

vs

```
(Double, Double) => Double
```

Note: a function can be `tupled`, which means a new function accepts all arguments in a single tuple. If you wish, your example can be made working by using:

```
combine(1,2,3, foo.tupled)
```

Answer (score 1):

To add (hopefully) a minor point of clarity to @Suma's answer, consider if you'd defined foo differently:

```
def foo(x: (Double,Double)): Double =  x._1*x._2
```

This works perfectly well as a function of a tuple2 to a Double. You could also write

```
def foo: ((Double,Double)) => Double = x => x._1*x._2
```

Or (to eliminate the ._ notation and enhance readability)

```
def foo: ((Double,Double)) => Double = {case (x,y) => x*y}
```

I suspect some one of these versions is how you thought you were defining foo when you wrote it down above.